# Google drive API does not work on IE11?

Tags: google-drive-api, internet-explorer-11

I have a JS application where after the user selects a file using the "Google Picker" API, I use the Google drive SDK to retrieve the thumbnail or export the body of the document. However, on IE11, whenever I try to do that, I keep getting a 404. The API calls all work on Edge, Chrome, FF, Safari etc., only failing on IE11.

Here is a sample:

```
Key Value
Request GET /drive/v3/files/<FILEID>/export?mimeType=text/html&key=<KEY> HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
X-JavaScript-User-Agent google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable    base64
X-ClientDetails appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.3%3B%20Trident%2F7.0%3B%20.NET4.0E%3B%20.NET4.0C%3B%20rv%3A11.0)%20like%20Gecko&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.3%3B%20Trident%2F7.0%3B%20.NET4.0E%3B%20.NET4.0C%3B%20rv%3A11.0)%20like%20Gecko
X-Origin    http://www.example.com
X-Referer   http://www.example.com
Referer https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.9jt-JkHEOKs.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNrivnJk2F0x6tjQPseAPkqN62frA
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host    content.googleapis.com
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
DNT 1

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: <FILEID>.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: <FILEID>."
 }
}
```

Is this a known issue in the Google drive API or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You encountered this error due to the file does not really exist or you doesn't have read access to the file you are trying to read as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#404_file_not_found_fileid).

Action you needed to do is to report to the owner of the file that it doesn't exist or ask the owner a permission to the file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can actually access the very same file on other browsers. I should also add that I am selecting the document using the Google picker API, and then retrieving more details about it using the Google drive API. It works on Chrome, FF and Safari, and even on Edge.